# Log silence deserialization problem from Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

In dealing with different versions of JSON data contracts, we sometimes encounter scenarios where the serialization library (e.g., Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json) silently handles discrepancies, such as ignoring missing properties or managing type mismatches (e.g., expecting a bool but receiving a string) without explicit errors. While Newtonsoft.Json provides mechanisms to hook into error handling for issues that would typically throw an exception, it does not explicitly cover these "minor" silently handled problems.

I aim to log instances where a data contract cannot be fully serialized or deserialized to ensure no critical information is overlooked or lost during the process. This logging is crucial for follow-up and data integrity verification.

Is there a way to intercept these silent issues directly with the serialization library? Alternatively, what strategies might be recommended for monitoring or handling such discrepancies to maintain data contract fidelity?

Comment: have you tried adding `[JsonRequired]` to all required properties? or the C#11 required keyword? If you want some kind of special handling you could always write a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

Comment: @JonasH, there is probably settings to enforce exception for handled problems but that is not what I want, I want to let it do what it can and if there is ANY problems I want to know about it so I can investigate it more later.

Comment: Probably those "silent issues" are due to the default setting for [jsonserializeroptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-8-0#web-defaults-for-jsonserializeroptions). Probably you would need to write your own [handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/missing-members) which will have small deviations from the base implementations - those that you need to monitor.